# Why is my Macro not working on other computers?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro on my computer, and it works perfectly. However, I attempted to add it to a coworker's computer, I keep getting a "sub or function not defined" error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSHeet()

 
'Copy cells from sheet1 and shows on sheet2
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:M10000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

 
'formula for cells E and F 

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E10000").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<>"""", SUM(RC[-4]*RC[-1]), """")"
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F2:F10000").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]<>"""", SUM(RC[-5]*RC[-3])-(RC[-5]*RC[-2]), """")"

'changes currency

Sheets("sheet2").Range("E:F").Select
Selection.Style = "currency"

 
'Lables columns for the formulas

Sheets("sheet2").Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Total Spend (Invoiced Amount)"
Sheets("sheet2").Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "Total Savings Amount"

 

End Sub
```

I have tried changing the name of the macro, referencing different cells, and writing the whole thing out vs copy and pasting it into the module.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. What line throws the error?

Comment: The "sub or function not defined" error could be caused by a missing reference to a library or module that is used in the macro. You should check that all the required libraries and modules are properly installed and referenced in your coworker's computer.

To check for missing references, open the VBA editor, go to the "Tools" menu, and select "References". Look for any items that are listed as "MISSING" and uncheck them. Then, try running the macro again to see if the error is resolved.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to check if the worksheet names match between your coworker's computer and your own. If the sheet names are different, that could also cause the "sub or function not defined" error.

Lastly, make sure that the macro is stored in a module in the same workbook that your coworker is trying to run it on. If the macro is stored in a different workbook or in a personal macro workbook, it may not be available for your coworker to run.

Comment: @BigBen The sub line with the name throws the error. Tried the fix's from techstud recommended and it still does not work.

Comment: Finally fixed the problem. I was using MS Teams to copy the code and send to the user before I went to their computer to install the Macro. When I stopped using teams and just retyped the whole thing again, it worked.